# ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_DBFULLSQL during publishing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have published my asp core website on smarteasp hosting. However I have found the problem that my local db has been not transfered so pages, where interectations with db are required, give me a error. Then I uploaded my db .mdf file and even been able to see tables and data on hosting panel page. However my site still works incorrect in those parts where interactions with db are required (while on my local all works correct).

So I decided to change my Web Deploy publish setting to include "Apply this migration on publish" and choose my migration named "Initial". Then even in preview menu all looks correct.

However when I push publish button I get **ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_DBFULLSQL**. I have been looking many links related to this error including official ones https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_DBFULLSQL but no one of them give me any understanding of sources and solution to this error.

So my primary question is how to resolve this error. Additionally I'd like to know if the inclusion of migration during web deployment could resolve the problem I described in the first paragraph.

Comment: It's looking like don't have permission to apply migrations (chceck user permissions). Ill recommend to make *.bak file of your DB and then restere it on your hosting

Comment: Thank you for the response! But I am unclear where to look for these permissions. Also *.bak file created by host automatically when I upload mdf file. I have recreated my db on host many times but it does not help.

Comment: I mean to create *.bak locally and then upload to hosting SQL

Comment: I have a .*bak file but I have permission to upload only mdf files.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you are @Bogdan, let me know if  you ever find a solution to this.

Comment: @Bogdan You can't only upload .mdf file on hosting environment. You need to upload full .bak file which consist of .mdf and .ldf file. You can upload .bak file and ask them to restore it for you. If you only upload .mdf, they wont be able to restore your db.

Comment: @Douglas Thomas I also read that .bak fle required (I did not find how to make it through VS). However, after I made changes in appsettings.json I have uploaded my mdf file succesfully and all works fine now (smarteasp hosting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **appsettings.json** I have changed DefaultConnection string to the one that represents **host** database settings including password (**do not forget** to set it in this string after your host provide it to you as he often writes ***** or YOUR_PASSWORD where your password should be placed). So it should look something like

```
"DefaultConnection": "Some code that your host should give to you;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

Also I put this string (Withot DefaultConnection) when I publish in database checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem with this error is the description of the error message.  If you try to read the linked messages, you'll definitely go down the wrong path.  I tried to setup user permissions all over my Azure site to no avail.

The problem is actually fairly easy to replicate.  If you delete your Web Deployment profile, then let publish create your profile by using the Microsoft Azure App Service button, you'll encounter this error.

Attempting to publish to Azure with the DefaultConnection set to the local connection string, you'll get the **ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_DBFULLSQL** error message

```
Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplication1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

So the solution is to go to Azure and copy the correct connecting string and update your profile.  I've asked Microsoft technical support to update the web page describing the error, or at best add a new error code.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when using msdeploy to publish a web deploy package to Azure. The error was caused by the use of a wrong connection string in file .SetParameters.xml. A connection string with a parameter name ending with "-Web.config Connection String" was used in the parameters file. This connection string is however intended for the web app itself. The error was solved after setting the deployment connection string, using a parameter name ending with "-Deployment Connection String".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to not deploy migrations.  Migrations requires full database control.